# How to create dynamic buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript

what is the proper way to create dynamic buttons that share a class.

in my case i have 2 inputs that share class

[image]

```
<div class="input-group">
<input autocomplete="new-password" rel="tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="La contraseña debe ser de 8 caracteres y tener al menos una letra minúscula, una letra mayúscula, un número y un caracter especial (#$%&amp;*+-;.:=@!_?/)" class="form-control password" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" aria-autocomplete="list">
<div class="btn btn-outline-dark visor" id="button" type="button">
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-eye-slash fa-w-20 icon" id="button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="eye-slash" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M320 400c-75.85 0-137.25-58.71-142.9-133.11L72.2 185.82c-13.79 17.3-26.48 35.59-36.72 55.59a32.35 32.35 0 0 0 0 29.19C89.71 376.41 197.07 448 320 448c26.91 0 52.87-4 77.89-10.46L346 397.39a144.13 144.13 0 0 1-26 2.61zm313.82 58.1l-110.55-85.44a331.25 331.25 0 0 0 81.25-102.07 32.35 32.35 0 0 0 0-29.19C550.29 135.59 442.93 64 320 64a308.15 308.15 0 0 0-147.32 37.7L45.46 3.37A16 16 0 0 0 23 6.18L3.37 31.45A16 16 0 0 0 6.18 53.9l588.36 454.73a16 16 0 0 0 22.46-2.81l19.64-25.27a16 16 0 0 0-2.82-22.45zm-183.72-142l-39.3-30.38A94.75 94.75 0 0 0 416 256a94.76 94.76 0 0 0-121.31-92.21A47.65 47.65 0 0 1 304 192a46.64 46.64 0 0 1-1.54 10l-73.61-56.89A142.31 142.31 0 0 1 320 112a143.92 143.92 0 0 1 144 144c0 21.63-5.29 41.79-13.9 60.11z"></path></svg><!-- <div class="icon fa fa-eye-slash" id="button"></div> Font Awesome fontawesome.com -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
<input autocomplete="new-password" rel="tooltip" title="Debe coincidir con la contraseña" class="form-control password" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation">
<div class="btn btn-outline-dark visor" id="button2" type="button">
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-eye-slash fa-w-20 icon" id="button2" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="eye-slash" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M320 400c-75.85 0-137.25-58.71-142.9-133.11L72.2 185.82c-13.79 17.3-26.48 35.59-36.72 55.59a32.35 32.35 0 0 0 0 29.19C89.71 376.41 197.07 448 320 448c26.91 0 52.87-4 77.89-10.46L346 397.39a144.13 144.13 0 0 1-26 2.61zm313.82 58.1l-110.55-85.44a331.25 331.25 0 0 0 81.25-102.07 32.35 32.35 0 0 0 0-29.19C550.29 135.59 442.93 64 320 64a308.15 308.15 0 0 0-147.32 37.7L45.46 3.37A16 16 0 0 0 23 6.18L3.37 31.45A16 16 0 0 0 6.18 53.9l588.36 454.73a16 16 0 0 0 22.46-2.81l19.64-25.27a16 16 0 0 0-2.82-22.45zm-183.72-142l-39.3-30.38A94.75 94.75 0 0 0 416 256a94.76 94.76 0 0 0-121.31-92.21A47.65 47.65 0 0 1 304 192a46.64 46.64 0 0 1-1.54 10l-73.61-56.89A142.31 142.31 0 0 1 320 112a143.92 143.92 0 0 1 144 144c0 21.63-5.29 41.79-13.9 60.11z"></path></svg><!-- <div class="icon fa fa-eye-slash" id="button2"></div> Font Awesome fontawesome.com -->
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
const input = () => {
    $(".visor").on('click',function() {
        var userChosenInput = $(this).attr("id")
        console.log(userChosenInput)
        visor(userChosenInput)
    });
}


const visor = () => {
    var cambio = document.querySelector(".password")

    if(cambio.type === "password"){
        cambio.type = "text"
        $('.icon').removeClass('fa fa-eye-slash').addClass('fa fa-eye');
    }else{
        cambio.type = "password"
        $('.icon').removeClass('fa fa-eye').addClass('fa fa-eye-slash');
    }
}
```

no matter what icon I press it changes the 2 icons and a single field, I want them to be individual behaviors.

[image]

Comment: You're calling `visor` with an argument but it doesn't accept any parameter. Instead it always selects the first `document.querySelector(".password")` and all `$('.icon')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also do the trick: One function for all buttons ...

```js
$(".input-group button").on("click",function(){
 $("i",this).toggleClass(['fa-eye-slash','fa-eye']); // change icon
 const inp=$(this).prev()[0]; // get the previous DOM element
 inp.type=inp.type=="text"?"password":"text"; // change type
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="input-group">
  <input autocomplete="new-password" rel="tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="La contraseña debe ser de 8 caracteres y tener al menos una letra minúscula, una letra mayúscula, un número y un caracter especial (#$%&amp;*+-;.:=@!_?/)"
    class="form-control password" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" aria-autocomplete="list" />
  <button><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="icon"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input autocomplete="new-password" rel="tooltip" title="Debe coincidir con la contraseña" class="form-control password" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation">
  <button><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="icon"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**just use an click event on button . you can use my below code . i hope this will help you**

```js
    let user=document.getElementById("user_password")
    let password=document.getElementById("user_password_confirmation");
    let show1=()=>{
        user.type=="password"?user.type = "text":user.type="password"
    }
    let show2=()=>{
        password.type=="password"?password.type = "text":password.type="password"
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="input-group">
    <input autocomplete="new-password" rel="tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="La contraseña debe ser de 8 caracteres y tener al menos una letra minúscula, una letra mayúscula, un número y un caracter especial (#$%&amp;*+-;.:=@!_?/)" class="form-control password" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" aria-autocomplete="list"/>
    <button><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="icon" onclick="show1()"></i></button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group">
    <input autocomplete="new-password" rel="tooltip" title="Debe coincidir con la contraseña" class="form-control password" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation">
    <button onclick="show2()"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="icon"></i></button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question doesn't directly specify whether to use jQuery or not, I took the liberty of doing it in vanilla js.

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control password" type="password" id="user_password">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control password" type="password" id="user_password_confirmation">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

```js
const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector)
const $$ = selector => document.querySelectorAll(selector)

const inputs = $$('input.password')
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  const button = $(`#${input.id} + button`)
  const icon = button.children[0]

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.type = input.type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-eye')
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash')
  })
})
```

Demo in [codi.link](https://codi.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%7C%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)